# SageMaker experiments store

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-experiments

I just started using aws sagemaker for running and maintaining models, experiments. just wanted to know is there any persistent layer for the sagemaker from where i can get data of my experiments/models instead of looking into the sagemaker studio. Does sagemaker saves the experiments or its data like s3 location in any table  something like modelsdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SageMaker Studio is using the SageMaker API to pull all of the data its displaying.  Essentially there's no secret API here getting invoked.

Quite a bit of what's being displayed with respect to experiments is from the [search results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_Search.html), the rest coming from either List* or Describe* calls.  Studio is taking the results from the search request and displaying it in the table format that you're seeing.  Search results when searching over resource ExperimentTrialComponent that have a source (such as a training job) will be enhanced with the original sources data ([result]::SourceDetail::TrainingJob) if supported (work is ongoing to add additional source detail resource types).

All of the metadata that is related to resources in SageMaker is available via the APIs; there is no other location (in the cloud) like s3 for that data.

As of this time there is no effort to determine if it's possible to add support into [modeldb](https://github.com/VertaAI/modeldb) for SageMaker that I'm aware of.  Given that modeldb appears to make some assumptions about it's talking to a relational database it would appear unlikely to be something that would be doable. (I only read the overview very quickly so this might be inaccurate.)